Can black holes fully merge, according to a distant observer?
According to a distant observer, an object falling into a black hole doesn't disappear behind the even horizon but rather red-shift due to time dilation.
Does the same apply to merging black holes? Does their mutual approach increasingly slows down, according to a distant observer, so that they don't fully merge in finite time?

This is only true in a fully classical picture. As soon as you add the necessary thermodynamic background noise in, then it's not true any longer. In that case objects falling into a black hole become invisible after a very short time. Same for black hole mergers. The remaining gravitational radiation signal falls below the background very quickly.

The distant observer can receive the gravitational waves from the black holes merging. Those are originally very faint waves that get more and more detectable, faster and greater amplitude as they get closer, and suddenly stops when the black holes finally merge. By measuring the sudden stop, the distant observer can definitively say that the black holes had merged, in their frame, at that time.

If a photon falls for a million years and hits a hypothetical hovering mirror, then the photon would return in another million years. A fall of ordinary matter conceptually is forever reversible. When two black holes collide, their horizons touch in seconds and that’s it, there is no going back. This collision is conceptually irreversible.

@safesphere, but how much time, according to a distance observer, does it take for event horizons to touch? Would the time dilation at the point where the horizons are about to touch make the process of merging infinitely slow at the moment of touching?

@Michael The horizon is where the time dilation is extreme. Figuratively speaking, the horizons are not affected by the time dilation, because they are the time dilation. For example, the time dilation doesn’t prevent a black hole from flying in space. The time dilation prevents (or slows down) the movement of physical objects relative to the horizon. This is called frame dragging, linear or rotational. For example, if a flying black hole hits a rock, the horizon would push the rock in front of itself. Similarly, when the horizon expands, it pushes all nearby matter out without swallowing.

@Michael Here is a mathematically correct video from numerical gravity of two black holes merging in the frame of a remote observer. It is quite evident that the moment the horizons touch, the result already is a single larger horizon of an odd shape that very quickly becomes spherical (strictly speaking, never exactly, but this is exponentially negligible): https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1M-AbWIlVQ

Black hole forms once there is sufficient mass in a volume of space. Once you get close enough to a black hole according to distant observer, it's event horizon will expand and swallow you before you cross the previous event horizon. With you close enough there is now enough mass for a larger volume of space.
